# ssh using private-key without password

Tags: linux, ssh, server, private-key

I have two servers A and B , i am trying to ssh from A to B using private-key and i don't want to provide password of server B.

I am trying below command for ssh ::

```
ssh -i <generated_private_key>  <user>@<host name>
```

the private-key is perfectly fine. but still this command asking for password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use ssh passwordless connection you need to place the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (id_rsa.pub is just an example could be anything you used durring generation) of the user@local_machine to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the some_user@remote_machine. 
Further if other issues exist then you should check `/var/log/` for the error.

**Edit1:**
Based on comments (thanks to @Crazy) if you used passphrase durring creation of the key then you need to recreate the key without the passphrase.

Comment: Here you are talking about public key , but i want to ssh using private-key

Comment: yes in order to use private key from your local machine to connect to the remote machine the relevant public_key must be in the remote authorized_keys file. if public_key exist to the remote authorized_keys file try to give the -i parameter full path of the private_key.

Comment: google: "private key remove password", example: https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO5292.html

Comment: Thansk @GiannakopoulosJ for your comments, But this is not related to passphrase. I didn't provide any passphrase while creation of the key. i think the problem i am facing related to "ssh_config" and "sshd_config" files. if the option for ssh using private_key is enabled or not. i still don't understand what is the actual issue.

Comment: @mahendra you are refering to  PubkeyAuthentication at /etc/ssh/sshd_config? this should be yes. Also validate the AuthorizedKeysFile to point to the .ssh/authorized_keys. posting sshd_config may help. also permissions of files should be checked. `chmod 700 ~/.ssh && 
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`